# angular2 d3: update d3 svg mouse pos to component property

Tags: d3.js, svg, angular

D3 is used to generate a `svg` in an `angular2` component. How to update properties `x` and `y` in component from svg event `mousemove`?

```
export class AxisComponent implements OnInit {
    x:number;
    y:number;     

    ngOnInit() {
        var svgWidth=400;
        var svgHeight=400;
        var margin = {top:25, right:25, bottom:50, left:50};
        var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg')
            .attr('width', svgWidth)
            .attr('height',svgHeight)
            .style('border', '2px solid');

        svg.on("mousemove", function(){
            var xy = d3.mouse(this);

            this.x = xy[0]; 
            this.y = xy[0];
        });
}
```

Error when accessing from `mousemove` event:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it should be:

```
svg.on("mousemove", () => {
   var xy = d3.mouse(svg); // or d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget);
   this.x = xy[0]; 
   this.y = xy[0];
```

Or this way:

```
let self = this;
svg.on("mousemove", function(){
  var xy = d3.mouse(this);

  self.x = xy[0]; 
  self.y = xy[0];
});
```

Comment: d3.mouse(this) is correct. However for some reason in angular type script reference this returns null. Calling it in commonjs that is embedded in a typescript ref still works.. still investigating.