# How to use 'this' in Angular with D3?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

---

**Tldr; How do I deal with `this` in reference to a D3 object when Angular binds `this` to the class (component/service)?**

---

I am looking to use D3.js (v.4) in an Angular (v.4) app.

My code works in standalone JavaScript but I now need to integrate it into an Angular app.

The use of `this` is tripping me up.

I have an SVG group that I wish to drag and so I use `.call(drag)`

```
someFunction() {
    this.unitGroup = this.svg.append('g')
            .attr('id', 'unitGroup');
            .call(drag)

}
```

My problem comes about when I try to reference the svg element that is being dragged. In my original code, I could refer to `this` e.g. `let matrix = this.getCTM()`. Using `this` is now not working when using this code within a service.

```
drag = d3.drag()
    .on('start', () => {
        this.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
    })
    .on('drag', (d) => {
        const m = this.getCTM(); // <--- PROBLEM HERE
        const x = d3.event.x - this.clickOrigin.x;
        const y = d3.event.y - this.clickOrigin.y;
        this.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
        d3.select(this) // <--- PROBLEM HERE
            .attr('transform', `matrix(${m.a},${m.b},${m.c},${m.d},${m.e + x},${m.f + y})`);
    });
```

Any pointers on how to implement this or clarification of what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

---

I don't think this is simply an error associated with the arrow function `this` binding as `.on('drag', function(d){...}` results in the same error.

---

**Here is Plunker illustrating my issue: https://embed.plnkr.co/p1hdhMBnaebVPB6EuDdj/**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

Comment: changing to  on('drag', function (d) { ... } ) doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker? You can try changing `this` to `drag` like `d3.select(drag)` Or maybe you are looking for `d3.event.currentTarget` instead of `this`

Comment: I'll have a look at doing that. I was hesitant to do so at first due to the amount of code required and I was hoping that someone would recognize my error.

Comment: See also related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350774/angular2-d3-update-d3-svg-mouse-pos-to-component-property

Comment: `.on('drag', (function(d){...}).bind(drag))`

Comment: @Castro Roy I suspect that `this.clickOrigin.x` and `this.setClickOrigin` are component properties while others should be current instance of d3 object

Comment: @yurzui, that's right

Comment: So have you tried `d3.event.currentTarget` or `drag` instead of `this` for instance of d3 object?

Comment: Yeah, console.log(d3.event.currentTarget) returns undefined.
In my original code, it would return the svg group being dragged.

Comment: I want to see it in a plunker) Here is my example of d3 https://plnkr.co/edit/qM3qrk3swvalQFBh1Db1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll take a look at that and create plunker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155258/discussion-between-neil-docherty-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In most of D3 methods, `this` refers to the DOM element, and it is the most simple way to get the element. However, you're facing some problems using `this` in your angular code.

The good news is that there is an **idiomatic** way to get the current DOM element without relying on `this` (and without relying on `d3.event` as well): using the *second* and the *third* arguments combined. This is quite useful in situations where you cannot use `this`, like your situation right now or when using an arrow function, for instance.

That alternative to `this` is extensively documented on the API. For most D3 methods, you can read that the method is...

> ... being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with **this** as the current DOM element (**nodes[i]**). (both emphases mine)

So, in a common D3 code, you can get the DOM element using:

```
.on("whatever", function(){
    d3.select(this).etc...
//              ^--- 'this' is the DOM element
```

Or:

```
.on("whatever", function(d,i,n){
//                         ^-^--- second and third arguments
    d3.select(n[i]).etc...
//              ^--- here, 'n[i]' is also the DOM element
```

Therefore, in your case, just use:

```
.on('drag', (d,i,n) => {
    const m = d3.select(n[i]).node().getCTM();
//the same of 'this'-----^
...
}
```

Since `d3.select(n[i])` is a *selection*, you'll have to use `node()` to get the actual DOM element.

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tjQ6lV411vAUcEKPh0ru?p=preview

Comment: Great! Thank you! The Plunker works as intended. To get this to work in my code I had to make a minor adjustment to get a typing error to pass -
 Property 'getCTM' does not exist on type 'Element'.

const m = d3.select(n[i] as any).node().getCTM();

Comment: Interesting. How about when `d3` is declared in my `AppComponent`, how do you reference `d3` without stating `this.d3`? In my case, I created the canvas on ngOnInit of AppComponent and I can't seem to refer to d3 without stating `this.d3`

Comment: @MichaelArdan Sorry, I'm not an angular user.

Comment: Very helpful thank you for `this` - Using angular and d3 together in a programmatic way is really a pain when it comes to stuff like this.

Comment: Great Thanks! I was also facing same issue for area graph, but this approach solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `d3.event.sourceEvent.target`:

```
.on('drag', () => {
  const target = d3.event.sourceEvent.target;
  const m = target.getCTM();
  const x = d3.event.x - this.clickOrigin.x;
  const y = d3.event.y - this.clickOrigin.y;
  this.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
  d3.select(target)
```

**[Forked Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/XLnGS6Yf2L22cMbOWMqt?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution! 

I've marked the answer from @GerardoFurtado as accepted as it seems more robust. When moving the dark-grey box in your solution, the event sometimes aprpears to switch to the larger box and then move that instead.

Comment: It solved one of them! I'm grateful for the help. Bonus points available in the next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423055/d3-zoom-event-firing-on-drag-in-angular