# D3 zoom event firing on drag in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

---

**Tldr; dragging the SVG causes it to rotate as well as translate.**

---

I am trying to implement dragging and zooming events on an SVG group using D3 (v.4) as part of an Angular service.

```
this.unitGroup = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('id', 'unitGroup')
  .call(this.drag)
  .call(this.zoom);
```

Dragging translates the SVG.

```
drag = d3.drag()
.on('start', () => {
  console.log('drag start');
  this.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
})
.on('drag', (d, i, n) => {
  const target = d3.select(n[i]).node() as any;
  const m = target.getCTM();
  const x = d3.event.x - this.clickOrigin.x;
  const y = d3.event.y - this.clickOrigin.y;
  this.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
  this.translate(target, x, y);
});
```

While zooming rotates the SVG.

```
zoom = d3.zoom()
.on('zoom', (d, i, n) => {
  const target = d3.select(n[i]).node() as any;
  const m = target.getCTM();
  const b = target.getBBox();
  const dir = (d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY > 0) ? 1 : -1;
  this.rotate(target, dir);
});
```

My original code worked fine. However, integrating it into Angular has thrown up some problems.

The current problem is that when you drag the `unitGroup` it triggers the `zoom` event along with the `drag` event.

The expected behaviour is that:

- 'click-and-drag' translates the small, dark-grey box in the x and y dimensions.
- 'mouse-wheel-scroll' rotates the small, dark-grey box around its center.

---

**Here is a Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/0GrGG7T79ubpjYa2ChYp/**

Comment: zone@0.8.18 is out. So your plunker should work now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, what you are seeing here is the expected behaviour.

In D3, `d3.zoom()` handles not only the zoom but the panning as well. So, the mousemove is being handled by `d3.drag()` and by the zoom function as well.

As Bostock (D3 creator) once said:

> combining these two behaviors* means that gesture interpretation is ambiguous and highly sensitive to position. (*zoom and drag)

Off the top of my head the simplest solution is just checking if you had a "real" zoom (mouse wheel) in the zoom function and, if you didn't (no mouse wheel), return:

```
if(!d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY) return;
```

Here is your plunker with that change only: https://plnkr.co/edit/jz5X4Vm9wIzbKmTQLBAT?p=preview

Comment: Indeed there is `stopImmediatePropagation()` inside d3.js library. But angular has some problem with handling it  https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19222 It is also zone js problem For example let's see at the example https://jsfiddle.net/hv5tLx9L/ Then include zonejs https://jsfiddle.net/08jzzjd5/

Comment: Commit https://github.com/angular/zone.js/commit/dcc285aab37bdd90b6d7133fc73045100861c61c was merged so maybe just need to wait new version of zonejs

Comment: Thanks. As my solution with `d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY` works, I just removed that mention to `stopPropagation`.