# Add class to axis if it has text

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-txvwep?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts)

It's a simple D3 bar chart in an angular app.

I want to check if the x-axis text has 'Feb' in it.

If it does I want to change it style.

In the exmaple here it is changing the color in the y-axis.

How check the axis has a particular name and style it.

```
private accessTicks(){
    d3.select(".x-axis")
      .selectAll('g')
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select("text")
        .filter(() => {
          return d3.select(this).text() === 'Feb'
        })
        .attr("fill", 'red'); 

      });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious problem here is that `this` inside an arrow function doesn't mean the DOM element. As a solution you can use the [third and second arguments combined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416334/5768908) or, easier, just the first one, which is the datum:

```
 .filter((d) => { 
    return d === 'Feb'
 })
```

Also, you can select all the texts at once (no need for those four selection methods you have). So, it becomes:

```
private accessTicks() {
  d3.selectAll(".x-axis text")
    .filter(d => d === 'Feb')
    .attr("fill", 'red');
}
```

Comment: It is possible to add a class to the `line` is above this text element that is selected here

Comment: @cdmt yes, after you have selected the text the line is just `this.previousSibling`. You can also just get the line directly, with `d3.selectAll(".x-axis text")` and the subsequent filter.

Comment: I had tried `previousSibling` but I get an error - `Property 'previousSibling' does not exist on type 'StackedChartCompoent'.` I have updated the question with how I'm trying to do it.

Comment: @cdmt please do not update your question, because it becomes a mess: I already answered what you asked. If you have a new issue, post it as a new question.